# How to calculate gaze position?

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I am trying to code out an eye tracker using Python. I am using the Face Mesh solution from the Mediapipe library to track the face, and I am able to get the x and y coordinates of the center of both irises.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
from tracker import Tracker

mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

tracker = Tracker()

with tracker.get_face_mesh() as face_mesh:
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, image = cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("Ignoring empty camera frame")
            continue

        image.flags.writeable = False
        image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height, width = image.shape[:2]
        results = face_mesh.process(image)

        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        if results.multi_face_landmarks:
            mesh_points = np.array([np.multiply([p.x, p.y], [width, height]).astype(int) for p in results.multi_face_landmarks[0].landmark])

            LEFT_IRIS, RIGHT_IRIS = tracker.get_iris_points()
            
            (l_cx, l_cy), l_radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(mesh_points[LEFT_IRIS])
            (r_cx, r_cy), r_radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(mesh_points[RIGHT_IRIS])

            center_l = np.array([l_cx, l_cy], dtype=np.int32)
            center_r = np.array([r_cx, r_cy], dtype=np.int32)

            cv2.circle(image, center_l, int(l_radius), (0, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.circle(image, center_r, int(r_radius), (0, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    
        cv2.namedWindow("MediaPipe Face Mesh", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.setWindowProperty("MediaPipe Face Mesh", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Face Mesh', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
            break
cap.release()
```

What I want to do next is to calculate where the gaze is pointing to on the screen. Are there any articles or code that I can refer to in order to do so? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you arrived somewhere? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @MazziottiRaffaele hi, nope i'm still stuck

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it by yourself using MediaPipe, you have to take into account several ideas and constraints, and these can change depending on the resolution you wish:

- Head position and angles (yaw, roll, pitch): Calculated from landmarks
- Eyes positions: Calculated from landmarks
- Iris position with respect to the eye landmarks: Calculated from landmarks
- Distance from the eyes to the screen monitor: If you have a depth camera, it could be easy
- Degrees of freedom: You can set them according to your requirements

However, you could probably find useful the next framework in python:
[https://github.com/pperle/gaze-tracking-pipe](https://github.com/pperle/gaze-tracking-pipeline)

Comment: In what context do you mean _degrees of freedom_ in this context?

Comment: In the context of trigonometry, when computing the angles and ranges to compute the gaze.